# Pause menu music after AudioListener.pause = true;

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a pause menu canvas with music and some soundfx of buttons, when I press ESC canvas gameobject becomes active and setting timescale = 0; and calling AudioListener.pause = true; to avoid in-game sounds play.

But when I call AudioListener.pause = true; Pause menu music and buttons' soundfx couldn't play too.

```
Pause = true;

            AudioListener.pause = true;

            transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.SetActive(true);



            Time.timeScale = 0;

            Time.fixedDeltaTime = 0.02F * Time.timeScale;
```

I tried to add another audio listener to new canvas but it is not working also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the solution with that code;

```
void PauseAllSources()
    {
        AudioSource[] allAudioSources = FindObjectsOfType<AudioSource>();
        foreach(AudioSource a in allAudioSources)
        {
            if (a.isActiveAndEnabled == true)
            {
                if (a.isPlaying) a.Pause();
                else a.UnPause();
            }
        }

    }
```

Replaced `AudioListener.pause = true;` with `PauseAllSources();`